# CSS&Angular: Different style for different behavior for childs

Tags: css

This is a general question, so the example is just for demonstration!

Let's say I have a parent div, and it has two childs in my Angular app.

```
<div class="parentDiv">
     <div class="child1"></div>
     <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

and I made a grid style at the parent for them to `grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;` and it works great.
but sometimes the `child2` replaced with `child3` so I don't want the parent to have the `grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;` instead different rule like `grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;`
How can I control the rules of the parent depends in its childs classes?

Comment: With JS you can since there is no parent selector in CSS

Comment: Sorry.. what? I don't think it help to myquestion